# Duplicate constraint error when using laravel syncWithPivotValue method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table (MySQL):

[image: Pivot table]

And this line of code in my asset model (mostly called by an async Job):

```
$this->sites()->syncWithPivotValues($sites, ['is_current_site' => true]);
```

My issue is that I have frequent duplicate constraint errors when I execute this line, and I can't figure out why. Any ideas ?

Comment: The sync family of functions does not seem to do any locking or transaction wrapping and is not thread safe so if you might run this accross multiple threads I suggest you lock the relevant rows and wrap this whole thing in a transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was facing was a concurrency problem between jobs.

I used the WithoutOverlapping middleware (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#preventing-job-overlaps) on my Job to prevent concurrency issues and it works well.